# How to use WIA on webpage to get image from client computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, wia

I am trying to figure out how to use WIA on a ASP.NET/C# web page to capture an image from a camera that is on the client computer.  The user will be using a Microsoft LifeCam camera and from my webpage I want them to be able to take the picture and store it in a database.  I imagine I will need to use DirectX for this and that is an acceptable solution but any solution would be great.

My big problem is I cannot seem to find any samples/documentation on how to do this on a webpage.  All I am finding is stuff that says it can be done but no explanation on how.  Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to generate a dll for the interface with tlibimp (from wiascr.tlb) which you can add as a reference in c#, then you can follow the tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629859(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Does this work on web pages?  Maybe I misunderstood something but the tutorial seems to be for creating a desktop application?

Comment: yes, but with scripting you should be able to create the same objects